# Is there any way to modify/delete the meetings using the service account in Exchange 2010/2007 (EWS)

Tags: exchangewebservices

1. Iam using Exchange Webservice (EWS) to create the meetings in exchange 2010 & 2007 for the user and the room using Exchange Impersonation(ie, user/Room will impersonate a "service account" so that the operations will be performed with the rights of the impersonated service account)
2. We get notification from exchange in case of any activity on the exchange as the user/room is subscribed for pushnotification. notification will have meetingid and changekey
3. When i create a meeting using EWS for a user (eg demouser) adding room (eg CONFROOM) as the resource using the rights of the service account (eg SAAccount), i get two notifications one is for the user and the other is for the room,iam storing the meetingid and changekey from the notification for both.
4. To modify/delete the meeting i have to pass the meetingid stored for the user as it is created by the user and it works fine.

Question: 
Is there any way to modify/delete the meetings using the service account, my intention is to modify/delete the meetings created by any user/room, because in my scenario I display all the meetings of the room (whose meetingid is different from the user's and this meetingid can be used to do accept/decline/tentatively accept and not delete/modify).

Thanks